# Duda Aplicación Web o Escritorio

Tags: php, c#, web, aplicación-escritorio

ante todo gracias por leerme.
Tengo una duda, estoy desarrollando un sistema de gestión para una inmobiliaria, actualmente estoy estudiando programación en la universidad.
Lo estoy realizando en C# aplicación Windows Form.
Yo sé PHP y .net y esta es una oportunidad por la cual estoy aprendiendo a hacer aplicaciones Windows Form.
La verdad es que por ahora lo vengo realizando bastante bien aún que recién e comenzado.
Pero un profesor de la uni hoy dijo que las aplicaciones de escritorio están desplazadas prácticamente por las web y realmente esto me dejó pensando.
Yo elegí hacerlo con c# primero por la facilidad de crear un programa y poder hacer un wizard para poder venderlo más fácil. También por la flexibilidad que tiene este lenguaje y muchas otra cosas más.
No se que hacer por que php lo domino bastante bien pero siento que si hago una aplicación de escritorio es más profesional. No sé, no sé necesito sus opiniones.

Muchísimas gracias chicos.

Comment: no es mas profesional hacer web o escritorio, eso es una mera suposición, el lenguaje y plataforma que uses depende de las necesidades del negocio

Comment: si lo haces en plataforma web también lo puedes vender fácil vendiendo una especie de renta en lugar de darles el sistema  completo, imagina tu que dices que decides hacerla solo para escritorio, cuando ese mismo sistema deba adminsitrar 5 sucursales como le harias? para que todas esten comunicadas en tiempo real

Comment: De la misma forma que la web, con una api de coordinacion. Hay una gran mentira en cuanto a web o no web. hay que saber cuando hacer una cosa. Y cuando tu profe te pregunte porque de escritorio, preguntale cuantas app web reales tiene y cuantas de escritorio. La pregunta esta basada en opiniones, y no tiene un formato correcto para este sitio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Una aplicación profesional es independiente de la plataforma para la cual fué construida, Facebook está diseñado en PHP y Skype para Desktop y móvil y todas son profesionales.

La calidad de una aplicación la define el equipo de trabajo que la fabricó, desde el arquitecto hasta el desarrollador.

Por otro lado c# no es exclusivamente un lenguaje de escritorio, puedes hacer exactamente el mismo Wizard y crear las mismas clases utilizando c# para WEB utilizando el Framework MVC de Microsoft.

Lo que si debes pensar es en la proyección y escalabilidad de tu producto, por ejemplo si lo harás crecer, si lo venderás como ejecutable o como le darás mantención a miles de usuarios al mismo tiempo.

Una de las grandes ventajas de tener un servicio WEB V/S uno de escritorio es que no necesitas desplegar tanto trabajo en una actualizacion, basta con realizar un deploy al sitio WEB y te asegurarás que todos utilicen la misma versión (siempre y cuando tu gestiones el aplicativo en tu servidor para todos), por otro lado si quieres vender el sistema WEB para que cada persona lo instale tendrás el problema del uso por licenciamiento, por ejemplo: ¿cómo te asegurarás que una empresa que te compre el software no se lo pase a otra empresa sin pagarte el dinero?, por este motivo existe una evolución en la venta de productos y servicios de Softwares:

**Primera generación**: Antiguamente las compañías creaban un ejecutable y lo distribuían pero este tenía limitaciones como por ejemplo: El manejo de licencias y las famosas dependencias, compatibilidades y otras cosas similares.

**Segunda generación**: Las compañías se dieron cuenta que tener una aplicación de escritorio tenía muchas desventajas tales como por ejemplo las dependencias, por ejemplo, para que tu Software fuese exitoso tenía que poder funcionar perfectamente en Windows, Mac y Linux en todas sus versiones, esto quiere decir, Windows 2000, XP, .NET y sin .NET y Windows 7, más OSX, entonces finalmente derrochabas dinero intentando crear una pequeña aplicación que fuese compatible con múltiples sistemas operativos.

**Tercera generación**: Luego de unos años comenzaron a potenciarse los Frameworks y Máquinas virtuales de ejecución tales como Mono, .NET, Java, etc, estos facilitaban los desarrollos en plataformas cruzadas o compatibilizaban diferentes versiones de un mismo Sistema Operativo, luego nacieron otros proyectos como NodeGTK y la gente comenzó a experimentar con aplicaciones híbridas que pudiesen ser ejecutadas en casi cualquier sistema sin mayores cambios, pero esto tenía un gran precio: El performance.

**Cuarta generación**: Con el tiempo nació el Bom! del servicio en la nube y los microservicios, esto daba muchas ventajas tales como por ejemplo: Ya no debes programar para multiples sistemas ni dedicarte a compatibilizar librerías, etc, sino mas bién desarrollabas un único sistema que funcionara en tu servidor WEB y todo el mundo hacía uso de el de manera Online, a demás, mantenías a tus usuarios actualizados y no tendrías nunca más a alguien desactualizado porque la plataforma es única, como por ejemplo Facebook, Gmail, Amazon WEB Services, Google Keep, incluso algunos sistemas de diseño 3d se pasaron a la nube con la llegada del HTML5 y el uso directo del Hardware de la GPU vía navegador WEB, como por ejemplo clara.io panzoid.com planok.cl etc.

**Quinta generación**: Mientras aun se daba la nueva era de la nube, el HTML5 y todo lo demás, mucha gente se adelantó un paso mas allá y se fue al móvil, como por ejemplo la migración de la app de Facebook de HTML5 a nativo, hoy muchas compañías están enfocadas mas en el desarrollo móvil que WEB, aunque esto depende mucho de tu público objetivo, lo mismo sucede con los juegos, hoy muchas compañías viven de las ventas en las apps de juegos y los micropagos.

Entonces, **¿Que es una aplicación moderna hoy en día?**, yo en lo personal ni si quiera perdería el tiempo en desarrollar la app web y me dedicaría a crear una app móvil para Android e iOS que hiciera lo que quieres hacer y subirla a ambos Store y ofrecerlas sin costo utilizando técnicas de micropagos por el uso de funcionalidades complejas, probablemente eso te dejará mucho más dinero que intentar vender una aplicación de escritorio y te desgastará mucho menos que crear una interfaz WEB en bootstrap o angular + fonts awesome + jquery, etc. Aunque de todas maneras tendrás que crear el servicio WEB del cual se alimentarán las aplicaciones móviles (para autenticar al usuario y guardar sus datos). Y recuerda, la capa de negocio (ejecución de la lógica) intenta llevarla al aplicativo móvil para que no te lleves toda la carga a tu servidor y no tengas que pagar mucho en infraestructura siempre y cuando no arriesgues la seguridad de los datos.

Comment: en serio? una app de gestion inmobiliaria para un par de empleados cargando movimientos sobre administracion de edificios en un telefono? Y no, actualizar una app de escritorio a esta altura tambien tiene cero costo (no tenes instalado steam? spotify? VS o VScode?)

Comment: Has utilizado alguna ves team viewer? sabias que su dasboard se migró a la web?, sabias que puedes utilizar spotfy via web?, de hecho si uso steam os y vscode no es tan completo para hacer apps transaccionales o complejas porque no tienen toda la funcionalidad de .NET, de todas maneras has escuchado hablar de Codeanywhere? Github?, pero vamos, cualquiera es libre de hacer lo que se le antoje, si quieres hacer una app en vb6 o usar papel y lapiz es tu desicion, pero no quiere decir que sea la mejor opción.

Comment: y tampoco la peor.. a eso apunto, todo depende de la aplicacion y lo que tengas que hacer. team viewer es de escritorio (por lo menos, tiene una version muy linda que se instala).

Comment: Amigo, has respondido practicamente despues de haber realizado mi post, ni si quiera te diste el tiempo para leerlo por completo, de todas maneras este post claramente no te va a servir a ti pero si al que hizo la pregunta, por lo cual no veo que sea una mala respuesta, me extraña que tengas tanto puntaje siendo una persona tan cerrada de mente con pocos argumentos y con poco sentido común.

Comment: sip. porque cuidamos las formas del sitio. no soy cerrado de mente para nada, y por eso tengo tanta rep. si quieres discutir respecto si estas preguntas se deben o no responder, te invito al [chat]

Answer (score -3):

Quiza esta no sea la pagina para contestar esta pregunta, pero mi consejo es que hagas la aplicacion como una aplicacion web, por muchas razones:

1. Usuarios no necesitan instalar nada puesto que en todos casos tiene IE, chrome
2. Puedes realizar parches de manera mas rapida puesto que solo deberas instalar la nueva version en el (los) servidor(es)
3. Si lo deseas despues, puedes lanzar a una version mult-inquilinos como un servicio en la nube.
4. En la mayoria de casos, los usuarios estan bastante familiarizados con las interfases de usuarios web.

Ahora bien,las aplicaciones web no funcionan en el 100% de los casos. Ejemplos:

- Aplicaciones con interfaz para hardward especial, caja registradora, lector de codigo de barras.
- Ingreso de datos via teclado rapido.

Aun asi, puede desarrollar un cliente enriquecido (Windows Forms, WPF) que se conecte por medio de llamadas web una API.

Entonces las decision se debe realizar en terminos de los requerimientos del software.

Comment: y no. no deben contestarse preguntas basadas en opiniones. ya que alguien podria refutar punto por punto todo lo que decis.

Comment: @gbianchi El usuario pidió opiniones por lo cual discrepo contigo y puede ser de mucha utilidad, a demas Stackoverflow en español no esta segmentado como la verison en ingles por lo cual no es una area de respuestas puntuales por sección.

Comment: si. esta en el [tour]. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son bien vistas en este sitio y se cierran.

Comment: dice claramente: No preguntes sobre..Preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones

Comment: @e-info128 No, las preguntas con problemas concretos se responden. Las que son basadas en opiniones se cierran. Te invito a que realices el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio ;)

Comment: @gaston. al parecer stackoverflow en español no podes hacer estas preguntas, por suerte hay un thread en stackoverflow habitual, podemos continuar ahi (ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511812/when-to-use-desktop-apps-vs-web-apps. Aca hay otra en stackoverflow tradicional muy buena (Ahora cerrada), las respuestas son increibles, saludos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072904/advantages-of-web-applications-over-desktop-applications.